# Webpage isn't resizing as the window resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently having trouble figuring out as why to my webpage isn't resizing with the window. If I shrink the window, the buttons go to the bottom, same with the main title, and they are both in white space. I have tried many suggestions such as using only percentages when it comes to fonts and width and things such as that, but not even that seems to be working. In the code it appears bootstrap isn't implemented, but I have it implemented through codepen.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<a name = "home"></a>
<div id = "wrapper">
  <!--linker to allow us to jump to 
top of page -->
  <ul>
    <!--setting up linker for home
-->
    <li><a style = "color:white" href = "#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a style = "color:white" href = "#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a style = "color:white" href = "#home">Home</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div>
  <img class ="make-ImageSmaller"src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469521669194-babb45599def?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=e32c5d5b5ea606e27bf29c40b4b3bb4f">
    <h2 class = "threeDLettering backGroundEditor">Front-End Developer</h2>
    <button id = "twitterButton" class = "clearButton btn btn-default spinner"><a target = "blank" style = "color:white" href = "" >Twitter</a></button>
    <button id = "instagramButton" class = "clearButton btn btn-default spinner"><a target = "blank" style = "color:white" href = "" >Instagram</a></button>
    <button id = "facebookButton" class = "clearButton btn btn-default spinner"><a target = "blank" style = "color:white" href = "" >Facebook</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.home-Background-Image{
  position:relative;
}
.backGroundEditor{ 
   position: absolute;
   text-align:center;
   top: 30%; 
   font-size:50px;
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
   font-family: Monospace;
}
#twitterButton{
  top:70%;
  right:59%;
}
#instagramButton{
  top:70%;
  right:43%;
}
#facebookButton{
  top:70%;
  right:27%;
}
.clearButton {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 15%;
    box-shadow: none;  

}

.threeDLettering{
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,
 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
 0 3px 0 #bbb,
 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
 0 5px 0 #aaa,
 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}


.make-ImageSmaller{
  width:100%;

}

ul {
  /*makes it so text can't go through nav bar*/
    z-index:500;
  /*Takes away the bullet points*/
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
  /*separation between the group, outside border*/
    padding: 0;
  /*Matte Black*/
    background-color: #333;
  /*Keeps bar in same place when scrolling*/
    position:fixed;
  /*What allows the bar to be able to stay stretch on the screen*/
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: right;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 /* WebKit and Opera browsers */
  @-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);    }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
  }

  /* all other browsers */
  @keyframes spinner {
    from {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
      transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
  }
.spinner {
    -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;

    animation-name: spinner;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

  .spinner:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }
```

Reading other posts some said to add the wrapper class to div, which I added, but not even that was able to get it to work. Any suggestions, or design flaws you may see, I am open to changing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I did this in codepen. First I nested your entire HTML code in a 'body' tag container and removed your 'img' tag

HTML

```
<body>
<a name = "home"></a>
<div id = "wrapper">
  <!--linker to allow us to jump to 
top of page -->
  <ul>
    <!--setting up linker for home
-->
    <li><a style = "color:white" href = "#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a style = "color:white" href = "#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a style = "color:white" href = "#home">Home</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div>
    <h2 class = "threeDLettering backGroundEditor">Front-End Developer</h2>
    <button id = "twitterButton" class = "clearButton btn btn-default spinner"><a target = "blank" style = "color:white" href = "" >Twitter</a></button>
    <button id = "instagramButton" class = "clearButton btn btn-default spinner"><a target = "blank" style = "color:white" href = "" >Instagram</a></button>
    <button id = "facebookButton" class = "clearButton btn btn-default spinner"><a target = "blank" style = "color:white" href = "" >Facebook</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Then I added this to your CSS, implementing your image here instead.

```
body
{
     background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469521669194-babb45599def?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=e32c5d5b5ea606e27bf29c40b4b3bb4f") no-repeat center fixed;
     background-size:cover;
}
```

Not sure if this is the proper way it should be implemented though, but this usually works for me.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Where was I going wrong exactly?

Comment: So CSS background image sorta does everything for you. But if you wanted to do it by 'img' tag like you did it, you would have to set the {height: } by pixel and not % so the height does not change. It's quite confusing but I think it's how html content works behind the scenes, if you notice when you drag from the side a website will either react to it (like text and images moving down) or it wont (like this stackoverflow website). So if you're only using one background image, do it by CSS, if you want different ones as you scroll down set height by px not %;

Comment: Actually, forget what I said in that last line for multiple background images and using px. Do not use the {height: px} method I just said for background images (I can't seem to edit my stuff here yet). Just stick to CSS {background: } stuff when it comes to making a background. After a bit of looking around, for multiple backgrounds I think you CSS as well. tldr: you should use CSS {background: } on your container element(in this case 'body') to add your background image in and not HTML.

Comment: last one I promise...did some testing, Here's a link on how to do multiple backgrounds [link](http://codepen.io/andrenaught/pen/aBOJKb), turns out you could use {height: px} to make them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, really appreciate it, how could I go about making something like this mobile responsive? I thought I did that in my original design, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No problem, sorry for confusing comments though. I actually don't know much about making a website mobile responsive. Here's a link to start though [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS add a height to .make-ImageSmaller ie.

```
.make-ImageSmaller{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that and I am still getting the same results. I am ultimately gonna have multiple pictures on the page, but want to get the first section of the page all corrected before I continue on.

Comment: Weird, i just tested with FF and Edge and it seems ok. I didn't have bootstrap included though, just the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Such as when I go to look at it from my phone, it won't show the title in the middle nor the buttons